# Which of the two versions is correct and why?

Tags: usage

The results are expressed in terms of percentage slowdown on a standard and a high-end PC.
The results are expressed in terms of percentage slowdown on a standard and high-end PC.

Answer (score 0):

Both are a bit awkward. Better to say,

> on a standard PC and on a high-end one.

---

Reasons for awakwardness:

The grammar in the second option you provide implies that "standard" and "high-end" are two attributes of the same PC. This is not what you mean though. In the first sentence, if we again took grammar over everything else, "standard" appears to be a noun. But this again doesn't make sense. We understand that the word "PC" is omitted there somewhere. So it's best to introduce "PC" in the first instance ("declare a variable", in a sense), and then just to point to it with a [deictic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis) "one".